# Angular 10, 3 levels of nested from group with array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

First: This is the project link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmadq6

So.. I have the testForm with 3 levels of formGroup, and the last formGroup is an array of formGroups.
(File app.component.ts)..

Thus, i want to click on checkbox and enable the price field.

I didn't know how to get the price control from array of this form group.

I know that i can disable it by using [attr.disable]="variable" but is it mixind TemplateDrivenForm with ReactiveForm, but, if don't have any way to disable it from ReactiveForm way, i'll use this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [method "get"](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get). See that you can "concatenate" using dots to reach the control and how we use the "index" "i". perhafs this example help you to understand the reason because we use `[formGroupName]="i"` in .html

```
checkboxChange(event,i){
    const enabled:boolean=this.testForm.get('price.rentPeriods.'+i+'.checked').value
    const control=this.testForm.get('price.rentPeriods.'+i+'.price')
    if (enabled)
      control.enable()
    else
      control.disable()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve the inner form array creating a getter for the form group first, and then accessing the array, as follows:

```
get InnerFormGroup(){ return this.testForm.controls.price as FormGroup; }
get InnerFormArray(){ return this.InnerFormGroup.controls.rentPeriods as FormArray; }
```

That way, you can access the array controls anywhere on your component:

```
onCheckboxSelect(){
    this.InnerFormArray.controls; //here you can access the array controls and disable/enable them
}
```